# What is decimal format exactly doing?

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
float result=(float) ( (new Float(result1)*0.3)+(new Float(result2)*0.7));
String a=dec.format(result);
vprosvasis.setText(a);
```

If I use `vprosvasis` somewhere else in my app, it will have the price `a`.

For example, if my result is `12,34`, `a` will be `12,3` so `vprosvasis` will be `12,3` if I write

```
float genikosvathmos = ((new Float(vprosvasis.getText().toString()) +
                         new Float(vprosvasis2.getText().toString()) +
                         new Float(vprosvasis3.getText().toString()) +
                         new Float(vprosvasis4.getText().toString()) +
                         new Float(vprosvasis5.getText().toString()) +
                         new Float(vprosvasis6.getText().toString())) / 6);
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of completely unnecessary boxing and unboxing.  But what exactly is your question?

Comment: I suggest you use `double` instead of `Float`, Is `getText()` not already a String?

Comment: NEVER use Float even if is not necessary!!!!
Use Double instead

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest using primitives (specifically, `double`) rather than Object wrappers (unless you have some need that you're not showing here).

Then look at the `Double` javadoc, especially the static utility methods:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

```
double myDouble = Double.parseDouble(myString);
String s = Double.toString(myDouble);
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `DecimalFormat` is to format numbers as text in a locale-specific way. (It can also be used to parse a locale-specific number format to a suitable `Number` type.) For example, in the American English locale, a period (`'.'`) is used as a decimal point, rather than a comma (`','`).

It is important to note that the `String` produced by a `DecimalFormat` is very likely to be incompatible with the format required for the `Float(String)` constructor. The string format consumed by `Float` is not locale-specific; it is a fixed format that is the same as that specified by the Java Language Specification for `float` literals in Java source code.

If you are doing calculations with money, don't use a floating-point type like `float` or `double`. Use instances of [`java.math.BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead. This type performs exact arithmetic, and when rounding is performed, you can control the rounding to conform with your accounting practices.

Answer (score 1):

Like Daniel, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to get from this post. But I will answer the question you asked in your title at face value.

You don't include the code where `dec` is declared, or any code where it's operated on, but from context it seems to be an instance of [the `DecimalFormat` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). If so, it's taking `result`, which is a `float`, and doing the following things:

1. widening it to `long`
2. using the [method `format(double number)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format%28double%29) inherited from `NumberFormat` to get the `String` representation of `result`
3. storing the result in `a`

Comment: Wouldn't a `float` be widened to a double for the [`double` overload of `format()`?](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format%28double%29)

Comment: @erickson, yes, indeed! Stupid typo on my part; I even linked to the right method. Fixing now.